# Cygwin terminal window empty

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, mintty

I've just installed cygwin (64bit) terminal on Windows 7 64. When I open cygwin terminal from Start menu, I can only see empty terminal window with blinking cursor. I can issue commands and see output, but prompt is missing (at least $ should be there, right?)

Any ideas how to fix it? It is fresh installation of cygwin on fresh Windows 7 64bit Enterprise.

Comment: In your Cygwin terminal, type `cygcheck -srv > /dev/clipboard`. This will put a *huge* amount of debugging text on your clipboard. Put it on one of the public text hosting services, like pastebin.com, then add the link to your question.

Comment: cygcheck output is here http://pastebin.com/HpiqH356

Comment: What is installed in `c:\ade` and `c:\aime`? Can you send me a link to a downloadable version of these packages, so that I can examine them for conflicts? What happens when you remove them from the Windows system PATH, and restart the system? You should also remove the ActiveState Perl and `c:\Python27` from the PATH while running Cygwin, and use Cygwin `perl` and `python` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Start with issuing the command

```
echo xyz
```

To find out if you are actually at a blank command prompt. If that responds with the output of `xyz` then check your prompt with

```
echo $PS1
```

And then set it

```
export PS1='\h \w> '
```

This should give you a prompt. If the first step itself does not give you a prompt you have other problems.

Another option is to start the `bash` shell from windows command prompt:

```
 c:>c:\cygwin\bin\bash --login
```

Assuming you have installed cygwin in `c:\cygwin`

Comment: It didn't help. The cygwin terminal starts 'C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -' The problem probably is with mintty.exe not with bash. 'echo $PS1' prints '$', which is correct, right?

Comment: Your `PS1` does not make sense...see PROMPTING in [bash manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)...if PS1 is $ you should see a $, not empty string as prompt. But it shows that mintty did start.

Comment: OK. I fixed it by changing 'C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -' to 'C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -e /bin/bash'

Comment: There you go...after checking that man page I was wondering what shell mintty is starting. So it did help :)

Comment: @Jan: What is the content of `/etc/passwd`? You shouldn't have to tell `minty` to start `bash`. It gets that info from your user configuration, so that has to be broken somehow.

Comment: entry for my account is 'jb:unused:somenumber:somenumber:ORA\jb,longnumber:/home/jb:/bin/bash' but i suppose, that it is not used. Maybe problem is, that cygwin does not mount c:\cygwin64 properly. I thought, that I fixed my issue, but I did not. I cannot even cat /etc/passwd in my terminal, because file is not found.

Comment: You might want to follow @WarrenYoung's advice about posting `cygcheck` output

Comment: I think, that I have finally fixed it by modifying cygwin.bat to run 
'mintty.exe -e /bin/bash --login -i'

Comment: As @WarrenYoung said you should not have to. There is an argument for fixing it now, but then http://xkcd.com/1319/

Answer (score 0):

First,
I'm using window64 too, but it can work with cygwin32, please try with cygwin 32

If not, please try install cygwin again from another miror